# Save the docker load output to another file

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I have txt file ( input.txt) which contains names of tar file

```
adminsrv.tar
alertmanager.tar
alpine-bash.tar
alpine.tar
authsrv.tar
```

I want run the below command on input.txt and save the output of the command on `output.txt`:

```
sudo docker load -i adminsrv.tar
sudo docker load -i alertmanager.tar
....
....
```

I tried

```
input=/var/tmp/input.txt
sudo docker load -i $input | tee  /var/tmp/output.txt
```

and

```
input=/var/tmp/input.txt
sudo docker load -i $input >> /var/tmp/output.txt
```

but i am getting error :

Error processing tar file(exit status 1): archive/tar: invalid tar header.

How can i can the expected output which is

```
Loaded image: registry.xyz-edge.net/adminsrv:v1.2022.0-onprem
```

on a file

Comment: Does it work without output redirect?

Comment: yes i works when i individually run the command in the directory where the tar files are save...

[root@Centos8 tmpimages]# sudo docker load -i adminsrv.tar 
Loaded image: registry.edge.net/adminsrv:v1.13.0-onprem
[root@Centos8 tmpimages]# sudo docker load -i alertmanager.tar 
Loaded image: registry.edge.net/alertmanager:latest
[root@Centos8 tmpimages]#

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```bash
sudo docker load -i $input | tee  /var/tmp/output.txt
```

into

```bash
(sudo docker load -i $input) | tee  /var/tmp/output.txt
```

So, you create an inner bash shell only for `docker load`, then its output will be captured by the pipe.

Let me know it works.

Comment: nope ( ) did not help however using while loop solved the problem
input=/var/tmp/input.txt
cd /var/tmp/tmpimages
while read -r line; do
        sudo docker load -i $line >> /var/tmp/output.txt
done <$input